# ListPlot only returning one value

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm newer to Mathematica language, and I'm having a big issue in graphing a set of points. It goes as follows:

```
f[w_] = expr.1
calculations = Table[expr.1, {w,0,numtimes}]
omegas = Table[i,{i,0,numtimes}]
orderedpairs = Transpose[{calculations,omegas}]
ListPlot[orderedpairs]
```

This returns a graph with just one point rather than numtimes amount of points, and it doesn't match the first point in the dataset. I've tried a listplot command for the two lists seperately, like

```
Listplot[{orderedpairs[[i]],omegas[[i]]},{i,0,numtimes}]
```

but i get an error that says "the expression i cannot be used as a part specification."

The data set is in the form x+iy, where x and y are real numbers. If I could get some help, I would appreciate it greatly.

Answer (score 0):

Plot the real by itself

```
ListPlot[Re[orderedpairs]]
```

Comment: What is `expr.1`?